# package using 3 cursor into 1

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

i have 3 functions:-

```
select function1(param1) from dual;
select function2(param2) from dual;
select function3(param3) from dual;
```

i want to use 3 of them in 1 package.

```
Create or replace package body PACKAGE_ABC

as procedure proc_abc(param1 varchar,param2 varchar,param3 varchar)

as 

cursor cur1
is 
select meaning from
table1
where meaning=(select function1(param1) from dual)

cursor cur2
is 
select meaning from
table2
where meaning=(select function2(param2) from dual)

cursor cur3
is 
select meaning from
table3
where meaning=(select function3(param3) from dual)

Begin
for cursor_var in cur1
loop
fnd_output.put_line(cursor_var.meaning )
end loop;
for cursor_var2 in cur2
loop
fnd_output.put_line(cursor_var2.meaning )
end loop;

for cursor_var3 in cur3
loop
fnd_output.put_line(cursor_var3.meaning )
end loop;

end proc_abc;
end package_abc;
```

is thr anyway by which i can use the 3 funcns in one for loop..... the 3 cursors select statement use the same table but are fetching diff values

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, it sounds like you just want your query to be

```
SELECT meaning
  FROM table1
 WHERE meaning IN (function1(param1), function2(param2), function3(param3))
```

Of course, there are a couple issues with this

- In the code you posted `param1`, `param2`, and `param3` are all undeclared.  So you'd get syntax errors if you tried to compile this.
- If you are only selecting the `meaning` column and you are filtering on the `meaning` column, there is no reason to reference `table1` in your query.  You'd simply want to select the result of the function call from `dual`.

Comment: i cant use in clause as the 3 functions are fetching 3 diff colums from the table......i want to print each of the meaning seperately

Comment: @user2187584 - Sorry, I don't follow.  It doesn't matter what column(s) are referenced by the function.  The only thing that matters is what the function returns.  In the code you posted, you indicate that it is valid to compare the return type of all three functions to the `meaning` column in `table1`.  If that is the case, you can use an `IN` clause. If you are saying that you want to compare the result of `function1` against one column and the result of `function2` against a different column, that is very different than what you posted.

Comment: i want to print by using fnd_output.put_line each of the meaning i get  from each cursor..... see i have edited and fetched meaning frm three diff table

Comment: @user2187584 - OK.  That's a radically different question then.  In your updated code, you've fixed the issue with the undeclared parameters.  But there is still no need to use any of the three tables since you are fetching the data from the same column that you are filtering on so you merely need to select each function from `dual`.  Do you want to make another change so that there is a need to use any of the three tables?